# Using buildah to create OCI images, how does one create an OCI "Bundle" image that can be passed directly to crun

Tags: containers, workflow, buildah

Using Buildah, I can create images for multiple architectures, and populate them trivially, and run the containers at will using buildah.  An embedded project, requires that I create an OCI "BUNDLE" (with config.json and mounted rootfs) which can be passed directly to crun (yes, CRUN, not RUNC), but it is unclear how to move from the OCI image (stored locally), to an image bundle using the buildah workflow.

Has anyone any experience with this?  What am I missing?  I have poured over the documentation, but it appears that my use case is (as always), a bit eccentric.  A pointer to documentation or tutorial would be ideal, but my search for same has thus far been fruitless.

Comment: Could you use [umoci](https://umo.ci/) for this purpose? I.e. `umoci unpack --rootless --image <image path/tag> <path where bundle should be created>`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we would hand of the driving of the container image to Podman.